# Perform segue after downloadTask has completed

Tags: ios, swift, swift3

I am building an app that once it is connected to a specific local network it displays an activity indicator then begins downloading a zip file of images, once the images have downloaded it unzips the file, stops the indicator and then performs segue to the next View controller. I have all the functionality working but don't know how to watch for when a function has finished. My Donloader class looks like this:

```
class Downloader {

    let documentsUrl: URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!

    required init() {

        self.load()
    }

    func load() {

        // Create destination URL
        let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("Images.zip")

        //Create URL to the source file you want to download
        let fileURL = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:4567/download")//FIXME for production

        //Create Session
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)

        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in

            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                // Success
                if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                    print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                }

                do {

                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                } catch (let writeError) {

                    print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
                }

            } else {

                print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", (error?.localizedDescription)! as String);
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

and my unzip function within my File class looks like this:

```
func unZip() {


    let zipFileURL = documentsURL?.appendingPathComponent("Images.zip")

    SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: (zipFileURL?.path)!, toDestination: (documentsURL?.path)!)

    var directoryContents = [URL]()

    do {
        // Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
        directoryContents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
    } catch let error as NSError {

        print(error.localizedDescription)
    }

    let pngFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "png" }//FIXME change file types if needed

    imageNamesArray = pngFiles.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
}
```

I've had a look at closures but don't understand how to call them from outside of the class or another ViewController. Any help would be great thanks.

Comment: Do you want to return some value from closure?

Comment: No, just wait for the download, then unzip the download, then perform the segue.

Comment: in your load function where you print successfully download call your unzip function there and after successfully unzip when you get your content perform segue. Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a completion handler without a return value is pretty easy. Change the `load` method to

```
func load(finished: @escaping ()->())
```

At the end of the task call `finished()`

```
  let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { ...

     finished()
  }
```

and call `load()` simply this way

```
load() {
  // task has finished
}
```

But with the completion handler you should delete `required init` and call `init` and `load` separately.

Answer (score 0):

You can try storing a completion closure in `Downloader` class.

```
class Downloader {

    let documentsUrl: URL =  FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask).first as URL!
    let completion: (Bool) -> ()
    required init(withCompletion completion: @escaping (Bool) -> ()) {
        self.completion = completion
        self.load()
    }

    func load() {

        // Create destination URL
        let destinationFileUrl = documentsUrl.appendingPathComponent("Images.zip")

        //Create URL to the source file you want to download
        let fileURL = URL(string: "http://127.0.0.1:4567/download")//FIXME for production

        //Create Session
        let sessionConfig = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        let session = URLSession(configuration: sessionConfig)
        let request = URLRequest(url:fileURL!)

        let task = session.downloadTask(with: request) { (tempLocalUrl, response, error) in

            if let tempLocalUrl = tempLocalUrl, error == nil {
                // Success
                if let statusCode = (response as? HTTPURLResponse)?.statusCode {
                    print("Successfully downloaded. Status code: \(statusCode)")
                }

                do {
                    try FileManager.default.copyItem(at: tempLocalUrl, to: destinationFileUrl)
                    self.completion(true)
                } catch (let writeError) {
                    self.completion(false)
                    print("Error creating a file \(destinationFileUrl) : \(writeError)")
                }

            } else {
                self.completion(false)
                print("Error took place while downloading a file. Error description: %@", (error?.localizedDescription)! as String);
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Also take a completion closure in unzip method.

```
func unZip(completion: (Bool) -> ()) {

        let zipFileURL = documentsURL?.appendingPathComponent("Images.zip")

        SSZipArchive.unzipFile(atPath: (zipFileURL?.path)!, toDestination: (documentsURL?.path)!)

        var directoryContents = [URL]()

        do {
            .. Get the directory contents urls (including subfolders urls)
            directoryContents = try fileManager.contentsOfDirectory(at: documentsURL!, includingPropertiesForKeys: nil, options: [])
        } catch let error as NSError {

            print(error.localizedDescription)
            completion(false)
        }

        let pngFiles = directoryContents.filter{ $0.pathExtension == "png" }//FIXME change file types if needed

        imageNamesArray = pngFiles.map{ $0.deletingPathExtension().lastPathComponent }
        completion(true)
    }
```

Initialise `Downloader` as below.

```
let downloader = Downloader { (success) in
    if success {
    let unzip = UnZip()
        unzip.unZip(completion: { (unzipSuccess) in
            if unzipSuccess {
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    //Stop Loading Indicator
                    //Perform Segue
                }

            }
        })
    }
}
```